# Making a copy of the second half of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to make a function that takes as parameters an array and a boolean. The boolean tells the function if the rest of the division of the array is to be included. It then returns a new array which is the copy of the second half of the first:

```
secondHalf({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, true) → {3, 4, 5}
secondHalf({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, false) → {4, 5}
```

For this assignment, I'm not supposed to use any other classes.
Here's what I've attempted:

```
static int[] secondHalf(int[] vector, boolean include) {
    int size = vector.length/2;
    if(vector.length%2 == 0)
        include = false;
    if(include)
        size ++;
    int[] vector_2 = new int[size];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < size){
        if(include)
            vector_2[i] = vector[i+size-1];
        vector_2[i] = vector[i+size+1];
        i++;
    }
    return vector_2;
```

Comment: Have a look at `System.arrayCopy`.  Should be pretty simple with that.

Comment: terminology nit: don't give a parameter of type `int[]` the name "vector", because vectors are a real thing in Java, and your method parameter is not a [java.util.Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html).

Comment: Sorry, in my native tongue we call it vector.  We're supposed to solved without using libraries.

Comment: `Vector` is just as much part of standard java as `Integer` or `String`. If you have an `int[]`, that's an "array", and using the correct terminology matters, as it means that everyone else familiar with java will understand your code, irrespective of their own native tongue.

Comment: The first comment pretty much has you covered already: create a half-sized array of the same type, and then use [System.arrayCopy`]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) to copy half the data over and return that new, half-sized array.

Comment: I'm not supposed to use that...This is an assignment.

Comment: Then please first update your post to say that it's homework and what the assignment restrictions are. Don't leave that hidden in the comments thread.

Comment: It's not hard to tell that this is a homework assignment, and what the assignment, and your teacher, says you're allowed to do. Asking about homework is fine, [but it comes with some additional requirements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/740553) compared to asking normal questions. Also remember that [a good question](/help/how-to-ask) still applies: please include what you're seeing your code do, how that differs from what you expected, and what you've tried to understand why it's doing that different things instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the size of `vector_2`, I've decided to use compound assignment operators. So the first part of this solution checks for the required condition and assigns a value to `size` in a single statement.

Since we know how many times to iterate over the loop, I think a `for` loop would be more appropriate than a `while` loop.

The loop retrieves all the values in `vector` from the middle of the array to the end of the array and places each value into `vector_2`.

```
static int[] secondHalf(int[] vector, boolean include) {
    int size = vector.length/2 + (include && vector.length%2 != 0 ? 1 : 0);
    int[] vector_2 = new int[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        vector_2[i] = vector[vector.length - size + i];

    return vector_2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

People have hinted at `System#arraycopy`, but with [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-int:A-int-int-) there is an even simpler method, where you only have to define the proper start index and directly receive the copy.

The start index is `array.length / 2` by default. Iff the `include` flag is `true`, then you have to add the remainder of dividing the array length by 2 to that.

An MCVE:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayPartCopy
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int array0[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        System.out.println("For " + Arrays.toString(array0));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secondHalf(array0, true)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secondHalf(array0, false)));

        int array1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        System.out.println("For " + Arrays.toString(array1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secondHalf(array1, true)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secondHalf(array1, false)));
    }

    static int[] secondHalf(int[] array, boolean include)
    {
        int start = array.length / 2;
        if (include)
        {
            start += array.length % 2;
        }
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, start, array.length);
    }

}
```

The output is

```
For [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
For [1, 2, 3, 4]
[3, 4]
[3, 4]
```